# A double sum with combinatorial factors

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$, $p$ and $j$ be integers. As a byproduct of some other calculations I have discovered  the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{p=0}^{j} \sum\limits_{p_1=0}^j \binom{p+p_1}{p_1} \binom{j}{p_1} \binom{2n-j}{j-p} \binom{n-j+p}{1+p+p_1} (-1)^p = \frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{2j+1}
\end{equation}

I used Mathematica to check that it holds true. The problem is how do I go about proving it?

Comment: One route is a counting proof: Find some situation where the LHS correctly counts some kind of object, and then show that one can also count it in the way implied by the RHS. (For example the $(-1)^p$ would probably represent some application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.)

Comment: I would go for proof-by-induction: Show for $j=1$. Assume for $j=m$. Prove for $j=m+1$.

Comment: How about your "other calculations"?

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be a complete answer but since this approach seems to me intuitive i will show it. This is a sort of ``by induction proof''. Let us look at the lhs for the biggest possible $j$ and then go down in $j$. We hope to see a pattern as a function of $j$ and thus guess the result.

So we take $j=n-1$.We have:
\begin{equation}
S(j=n-1)= \sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum\limits_{p_1=0}^{n-1} \binom{p+p_1}{p_1} \binom{n-1}{p_1} \binom{n+1}{n-1-p} \binom{1+p}{1+p+p_1}
\end{equation}
Since the last binomial factor on the right equals $\delta_{p_1,0}$, we have:
\begin{equation}
S(j=n-1)= \sum\limits_{p=2}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{p} (-1)^p = \frac{1}{2} \binom{2 n}{1} = rhs
\end{equation}

Now we take $j=n-2$.We have:
\begin{equation}
S(j=n-2)= \sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-2} \sum\limits_{p_1=0}^{n-2} \binom{p+p_1}{p_1} \binom{n-2}{p_1} \binom{n+2}{n-2-p} \binom{2+p}{1+p+p_1}
\end{equation}
Since the last binomial factor on the rhs equals $\delta_{p_1,0} (2+p) + \delta_{p_1,1}$ we have:
\begin{equation}
S(j=n-2)= \sum\limits_{p=4}^{n+2} \binom{n+2}{p}\left[(p-2) + (p-3)(n-2)\right](-1)^p = \frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{3} = rhs
\end{equation}

Now we take $j=n-3$. We have:
\begin{equation}
S(j=n-3)= \sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-3} \sum\limits_{p_1=0}^{n-3} \binom{p+p_1}{p_1} \binom{n-3}{p_1} \binom{n+3}{n-3-p} \binom{3+p}{1+p+p_1}
\end{equation}

Since the last binomial factor on the rhs equals $\delta_{p_1,0} \binom{p+3}{2} + \delta_{p_1,1} \binom{p+3}{1} + \delta_{p_1,2}$ we have:
\begin{align}
S(j=n-3)
&= \sum\limits_{p=6}^{n+3} \binom{n+3}{p}\Big[\binom{p-3}{2} 
+ \binom{p-3}{1}(p-5)(n-3) \\& \hspace{3cm} + \binom{p-4}{2} \binom{n-3}{2}\Big](-1)^p = \frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{5} = rhs
\end{align}

As we go down in $j$ we always do the sum over $p_1$ using properties of the delat function and we end up with a couple of sums over $p$ each of which are elementary. The only thing that remains is to write down all those sums and compute them. Yet, since the pattern has already emerged I quit at this stage..

Comment: I edited your Mathjax slightly so that the last few equations didn't overflow the answer width. Let me know if I mixed something up.